# why does my raycast stop working after a few seconds?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, timing, raycasting

i have a gun that uses a raycast to detect an enemy. before this code was working perfectly but now 
  when 
   i shoot an enemy after i wait a couple seconds the raycast does not detect the enemy this is the gun code

```
using System.Collections;
   using UnityEngine;

   public class Gun : MonoBehaviour
   {
    public float damage = 25f;
    public float range = .00000000000000000000000001f;
    public float fireRate = 1f;

   public int maxAmmo = 5;
    private int currentAmmo;
    public float reloadTime = 3f;
   public bool isReloading = true;

    public Camera fpsCam;
    public ParticleSystem MuzzleFlash;
    public GameObject impactEffect;
    public float impactForce = 30f;

    private float nextTimeToFire = 0f;

    public Animator animator;



    private void Start()
    {
        currentAmmo = maxAmmo;


    }

    void OnEnable()
    {
        isReloading = false;
        animator.SetBool("Reloading", false);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

        if (isReloading)
            return;


        if (currentAmmo <= 0)
        {
          StartCoroutine(Reload());
            return;
        }

        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1") && Time.time >= nextTimeToFire)
        {
            nextTimeToFire = Time.time + 1f / fireRate;
            Shoot();
        }
    }

    IEnumerator Reload()
    {
        isReloading = true;
        Debug.Log("RELOAD");

        animator.SetBool("Reloading", true);

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(reloadTime - .25f);
        animator.SetBool("Reloading", false);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(.25f);

        currentAmmo = maxAmmo;


        isReloading = false;

    }

    void Shoot()
    {
        MuzzleFlash.Play();

        currentAmmo--;

        RaycastHit hit;
        if (Physics.Raycast(fpsCam.transform.position, fpsCam.transform.forward, out hit, range))
        {
            Debug.Log(hit.transform.name);

            Enemy enemy = hit.transform.GetComponent<Enemy>();
            if (enemy != null)
            {
                enemy.TakeDamage(damage);
            }

            if (hit.rigidbody != null)
            {
                hit.rigidbody.AddForce(hit.normal * impactForce);
            }


            if (isReloading == true)
            {
                animator.SetBool("Shooting", false);

            }
        }

        GameObject impactGO =  Instantiate(impactEffect, hit.point, 
   Quaternion.LookRotation(hit.normal));
        Destroy(impactGO, 2f);

    }
   }
```

here is the enemy script

```
    **public class Enemy : MonoBehaviour
   {
    public float health = 50f;

    public void TakeDamage(float amount)
    {
        health -= amount;

        if (health <= 0f)
        {
            Die();
        }
    }



    void Die ()
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }

   }
```

this started happening after i added anenemy controller and animator to the enemy the raycast woukd hit.

Comment: heres a video displaying it https://youtu.be/SXuTczhN7iY

Comment: Sadly the video doesnt add a lot of context as its unclear what you expected to happen.  Your raycast doesnt seem to allow for the fact you may hit your own playercolider, so the raycast does fail if it starts inside a collider and isnt told to ignore it.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issue and I have spend hours to figure it out what is happening. If you are using Nav Mesh Agent and Rigidbody on the enemy at same time try to change Collision Detection to "Continuous" instead of "Discrete".

I found this old post which helps me out:
https://answers.unity.com/questions/658434/why-do-raycasts-ignore-navmesh-agents.html

Answer (score 0):

When the range is so small, the weapon needs to be really close to enemy's collider. Try increasing it to 10.0f.

Comment: thanks, that didnt work since the ingame float was already 40.

Answer (score 0):

ok my game just made me redo some stuff and it finally works for some reason and i geuss the reason was beacause i was using a prefab since that is the only difference.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and making the enemy's rigidbody kinematic worked for me